# Cannot call SpeechClient.recognize(RecognizeRequest request): Throwing Exception

Tags: android, exception, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

This is my first time posting, so I'm not too familiar with the rules, but here goes.
I've been trying to get the Google Cloud Speech API to work on Android, but to no avail. The same code works just fine on Java, but not on Android.
My code runs fine until I call the recognize method, using a speech client.
Here is the error:

```
11-02 18:38:03.922 6959-6982/capstone.speechrecognitionsimple E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: capstone.speechrecognitionsimple, PID: 6959
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService io.grpc.internal.ClientTransportFactory.getScheduledExecutorService()"
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1319)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1311)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:53)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:114)
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.recognize(SpeechClient.java:245)
    at capstone.speechrecognitionsimple.MainActivity$InitTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:94)
    at capstone.speechrecognitionsimple.MainActivity$InitTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:38)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
 Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService io.grpc.internal.ClientTransportFactory.getScheduledExecutorService()"
    at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.getScheduledExecutorService(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:52)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:557)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:59)
    at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:536)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectCallable.newCall(GrpcDirectCallable.java:76)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectCallable.futureCall(GrpcDirectCallable.java:70)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:65)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcAttemptCallable.call(GrpcAttemptCallable.java:80)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcRetryingCallable.futureCall(GrpcRetryingCallable.java:64)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcRetryingCallable.futureCall(GrpcRetryingCallable.java:46)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.EntryPointUnaryCallable.futureCall(EntryPointUnaryCallable.java:70)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:89)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:114) 
    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.recognize(SpeechClient.java:245) 
    at capstone.speechrecognitionsimple.MainActivity$InitTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:94) 
    at capstone.speechrecognitionsimple.MainActivity$InitTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:38) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I don't know why this is happening. Here is my code:

```
package capstone.speechrecognitionsimple;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionAudio;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeRequest;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeResponse;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionAlternative;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionResult;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechSettings;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InitTask init = new InitTask();
        init.execute();

    }


    class InitTask extends AsyncTask<ByteString, Void, String> {
        SpeechClient speechClient = null;
        protected String doInBackground(ByteString... strings) {
            String transcript = "Transcript:\n";
            try {
                Log.i("InitTask", "Creating client...");

                InputStream credentialsStream = getAssets().open("credentials.json");
                GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream);
                FixedCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials);

                InputStream path = getAssets().open("audio.raw");
                byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(path);
                ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

                SpeechSettings speechSettings =
                        SpeechSettings.newBuilder()
                                .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                                .build();

                Log.i("InitTask", "Settings Created");

                speechClient = SpeechClient.create(speechSettings);

                Log.i("InitTask", "Client Created");

                RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding encoding = RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16;
                Log.i("InitTask", "Encoding Created");

                int sampleRateHertz = 16000;
                String languageCode = "en-US";
                RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                        .setEncoding(encoding)
                        .setSampleRateHertz(sampleRateHertz)
                        .setLanguageCode(languageCode)
                        .build();

                Log.i("finalRec", "Config Created");

                RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
                        .setContent(audioBytes)
                        .build();
                Log.i("finalRec", "Audio Created");
                RecognizeRequest request = RecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setConfig(config)
                        .setAudio(audio)
                        .build();

                RecognizeResponse response = speechClient.recognize(request);
                Log.i("finalRec", "Called RECOGNIZE");


                List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();

                for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
                    List<SpeechRecognitionAlternative> alternatives = result.getAlternativesList();
                    for (SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative : alternatives) {
                        transcript+= alternative.getTranscript();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Client", "" + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                speechClient.close();
            }  catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Client", "" + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return transcript;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String transcript) {
            Log.i("Transcript", "" +transcript);
        }
    }
}
```

And last, here's my gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

ext {
    grpcVersion = '1.4.0'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "capstone.speechrecognitionsimple"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        javaCompileOptions{
            annotationProcessorOptions{
                includeCompileClasspath = true
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider'
        exclude 'project.properties'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.3.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
                grpc {
                    // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    provided 'com.jakewharton.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.4'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.4.1'

    // gRPC
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpcVersion"
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:$grpcVersion"
    compile "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion"
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.3.1'

    compile group: 'com.google.api.grpc', name: 'grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1', version: '0.1.13'
    compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-speech', version: '0.26.0-alpha'

    // OAuth2 for Google API
    compile('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.7.0') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech   is an android sample of grpc speech. did u start with that?

Comment: Yes, I ran that just fine a while back, but it's using streaming recognition when I only want synchronous recognition.

Comment: then just drop the grpc and change the api call..  stick with the android template . modify its components to suit your use case rather than trying to force a java.lang sample to build and to run on android.  Can u not drop the grpc stuff ( u dont need streaming ) and then just change the speech api calls to do what u want?

Comment: I suppose I can do that, though I'm still interested in the cause of the exceptions,

Comment: you got protocol buffers confliction with java.util.concurrency  .  if you do not need streaming/continuous response then why have all the complexity of grpc in your runtime . u can call google speech over http if u dont need a realtime stream.

Comment: im not sure that the java examples are a better place to start than the android examples. ;you might try keeping it simple ... drop grpc if it is not needed. build on a sample for android that u find somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Protobuf.  For others running into this issue, make sure you have the following in your top-level build.gradle:

classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.6'