# I'm trying to use google's speech to text api for android. Getting an error when setting the credentials in speechClient

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to instantiate speechClient object with credentials in android. To use it later for transforming audio input into text.

My code looks like this:

```
val speechSettings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder()
            .setCredentialsProvider(
                FixedCredentialsProvider.create(
                    GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                        context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.my_key_name)
                    )
                )
            )
            .build()

val speechClient = SpeechClient.create(speechSettings)
```

and in gradle I added the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.80.0-beta'
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.4.0"
```

I get the following error when running the application:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService io.grpc.internal.ClientTransportFactory.getScheduledExecutorService()"
```

Full stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService io.grpc.internal.ClientTransportFactory.getScheduledExecutorService()"
        at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.getScheduledExecutorService(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:52)
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.<init>(ManagedChannelImpl.java:560)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:419)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:222)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:164)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:156)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:157)
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.stub.GrpcSpeechStub.create(GrpcSpeechStub.java:94)
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.stub.SpeechStubSettings.createStub(SpeechStubSettings.java:126)
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.<init>(SpeechClient.java:144)
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:126)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot call SpeechClient.recognize(RecognizeRequest request): Throwing Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085738/cannot-call-speechclient-recognizerecognizerequest-request-throwing-exception)

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace?

Comment: @David included full stacktrace.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev it doesn't answer my question.